# docxtemplater in Vue js error Failed to read responseText on android

Tags: android, django, vue.js, chromium

I have created a frontend app with Vue js on the Quasar framework, it works very well on the browser. But when I run it on android by using Cordova it does not work properly when it loads an MS word file from a remote server to fill it with some data. For templating I am using [docxtemplater](https://docxtemplater.com/docs). And I take the following error:

Error: InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'arraybuffer').

In addition, I have used the Django framework as a server with Nginx, Gunicorn on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.
[the site works via https](https://tub-aspergillosis.uz/)

Cordova 11.0.0
Android 10.0 (Q) API level 29
Django settings:

```
"""
Django settings for tuberculosis project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'some-key'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', '75.119.133.43', 'www.tub-aspergillosis.uz', 'tub-aspergillosis.uz']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'patientapp.apps.PatientappConfig',
    'ai.apps.AIConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

# **Dont forget to add your client's address to the CORS whitelist. This will make sure the server accepts request from
# the specified source only
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:8000', 'http://75.119.133.43:8000', 'http://tub-aspergillosis.uz', 'https://tub-aspergillosis.uz'
]

# allow all requests containing any of the default headers(as in django docs) or content-type header
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + (
    'contenttype',
)


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tuberculosis.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tuberculosis.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'app',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = str(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR.replace('\\', '/') + STATIC_URL,
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}

# Localizing date and time => day-month-year
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y']

from datetime import timedelta
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=1440),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

Comment: Hello @Musulmon, I'm the creator of docxtemplater.

Can you add some more details about your server ? The exact code that you're using serverside would be interesting to have, or a live instance.

Comment: Which version of Android and of cordova are you using ?

Comment: @edi9999 Thanks, for your reply, I have edited as you say if you want to know other things, please write I try to do it as possible as I can.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the network tab and the details of the request ?
Also, maybe it would be simpler if we had a small debugging session on teams, can you contact me privately per email ? My email is on https://docxtemplater.com/ in the footer